# How can I break up a large tif file into multiple UIImage's for display in a UIImageView?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage

I am consuming a web service that is returning electronic faxes in the form of tif (base 64 encoded text). The thing is it is returning multi-page faxes as one large tiff file and ideally I want the user to be able to click through the various pages. When I decode the text and display, it only shows the first page in the UIImageView.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: if the final uiimage contains the complete image, then u can calculate the number of pages using the dimensions of the image, then render specific areas of the image...

Comment: yes but how do you paginate a tif file?

Comment: rendering different areas of the image i suppose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've create my own solution for this: [NSTiffSplitter](https://github.com/Sharrp/NSTiffSplitter).
You can find it on [github](https://github.com/Sharrp/NSTiffSplitter).

```
NSString *pathToImage = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Example" ofType:@"tiff"];
NSTiffSplitter* splitter = [[NSTiffSplitter alloc] initWithPathToImage:pathToImage];
UIImage *page = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[splitter dataForImage:page]];
yourImageView.image = page;
[page release];
```